# (Leetcode) Minesweeper game

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, depth-first-search

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/minesweeper/) -

> *Let's play the Minesweeper game
>   ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minesweeper_(video_game)),
>   [online game](http://minesweeperonline.com/))!*
>
> *You are given a 2D char matrix representing the game board. '**M**'
>   represents an **unrevealed** mine, '**E**' represents an
>   **unrevealed** empty square, '**B**' represents a **revealed** blank square that has no adjacent (above, below, left, right, and all 4
>   diagonals) mines, **digit** (`1` to `8`) represents how many mines are
>   adjacent to this **revealed** square, and finally '**X**' represents a
>   **revealed** mine.*
>
> *Now given the next click position (row and column indices) among all
>   the **unrevealed** squares (`M` or `E`), return the board after
>   revealing this position according to the following rules -*
>
> - *If a mine (`M`) is revealed, then the game is over - change it to '**X**'.*
> - *If an empty square (`E`) with **no adjacent mines** is revealed, then change it to a revealed blank (`B`) and all of its adjacent
>     **unrevealed** squares should be revealed recursively.*
> - *If an empty square (`E`) with **at least one adjacent mine** is revealed, then change it to a digit (`1` to `8`) representing the
>     number of adjacent mines.*
> - *Return the board when no more squares will be revealed.*
>
> ***Example 1*** -
>
> ```
> Input: 
>
> [['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
>  ['E', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'E'],
>  ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
>  ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']]
>
> Click : [3,0]
>
> Output: 
>
> [['B', '1', 'E', '1', 'B'],
>  ['B', '1', 'M', '1', 'B'],
>  ['B', '1', '1', '1', 'B'],
>  ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
> ```
>
> ***Explanation*** -
>
> [image]
>
> ***Example 2*** -
>
> ```
> Input: 
>
> [['B', '1', 'E', '1', 'B'],
>  ['B', '1', 'M', '1', 'B'],
>  ['B', '1', '1', '1', 'B'],
>  ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
>
> Click : [1,2]
>
> Output: 
>
> [['B', '1', 'E', '1', 'B'],
>  ['B', '1', 'X', '1', 'B'],
>  ['B', '1', '1', '1', 'B'],
>  ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
> ```
>
> ***Explanation*** -
>
> [image]
>
> ***Note*** -
>
> - *The range of the input matrix's height and width is `[1,50]`.*
> - *The click position will only be an unrevealed square (`M` or `E`), which also means the input board contains at least one clickable
>     square.*
> - *The input board won't be a stage when the game is over (some mines have been revealed).*
> - *For simplicity, not mentioned rules should be ignored in this problem. For example, you **don't** need to reveal all the unrevealed
>     mines when the game is over, consider any cases that you will win the
>     game or flag any squares.*

Here is my solution to this challenge -

```
class Solution:

    directions = [(-1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (0,-1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]

    def updateBoard(self, board, click):
        """
        :type board: List[List[str]]
        :type click: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[str]]
        """
        return self.dfs(board, click)

    def dfs(self, board, click):
        stack = [(click[0], click[1])]
        m, n = len(board), len(board[0])
        while stack:
            r, c = stack.pop() # last inserted element

            if board[r][c] == 'M':
                board[r][c] = 'X'
                break

            # check for adjacent mines
            mines = 0
            for i, j in self.directions:
                dr = r + i
                dc = c + j
                if 0 <= dr < m and 0 <= dc < n and board[dr][dc] == 'M':
                    mines += 1
            board[r][c] = str(mines) if mines else 'B'

            # add neighbors
            for i, j in self.directions:
                dr = r + i
                dc = c + j
                if 0 <= dr < m and 0 <= dc < n and board[r][c] == 'B' and board[dr][dc] == 'E':
                    stack.append((dr, dc))

        return board
```

Here is my Leetcode result (54 test cases) -

[image]

So, I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of repeating `0 <= dr < m` and `0 <= dc < n` tests in the mine counting loop and the recursive search step, looping over the 2x2, 2x3, 3x2 or 3x3 grid for any `r,c` coordinate might be better done using a generator expression, using ranges:

```
while stack:
    r, c = stack.pop()

    rows = range(max(0, r-1), min(r+2, m))
    cols = range(max(0, c-1), min(c+2, n))

    mines = sum(1 for i in rows for j in cols if board[i][j] == 'M')
```

As a bonus, you get to reuse those ranges if you find a blank square, for the queuing of virtual click coordinates.

```
    if mines:
        board[r][c] = str(mines)
    else:
        board[r][c] = 'B'
        for i in rows:
            for j in cols:
                if board[i][j] == 'E':
                    stack.append((i, j))
```

---

When you click on a square, and find it is empty, and there are no mines around it, you mark it `B`, and immediately "click" every `E` square around it (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `f`, `g`, `h`, & `i`):

```
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . a b c . . .
. . d B f . . .
. . g h i . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
```

This adds positions `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `f`, `g`, `h`, & `i` to `stack`.  You pop position `i` off the stack, and if it turns out to also be surrounded by 0 mines, you add its `E` neighbours to `stack`, including `f` and `h` a second time.  Eventually, you'll pop `h` off the stack, and add if it is surrounded by zero mines, add `d` & `g` a second time, and `f` a third time.  This leads to needlessly counting up the mines around various positions multiple times during one `dfs` call.  Needless repeated counting will, of course, waste time and slow your algorithm down.

Instead of using a `list` as a `stack`, you could use a `set`, which would ignore any duplicate coordinates which are attempted to be queued for subsequent processing.

Alternately, you could mark the "just queued" position with a different symbol, say `_`, which will eventually be filled in with the number of mines surrounding that square (or `B`) once that position is popped off the stack for processing.  However, it will no longer be an `E`, so it won't be accidentally queued multiple times.

```
    else:
        for i in rows:
            for j in cols:
                if board[i][j] == 'E':
                    stack.append((i, j))
                    board[i][j] = '_'    # Temporary mark to prevent repeated queueing
```

---

Using slices for counting the number of mines may be slightly faster, due to the fewer indexing operations:

```
while stack:
    r, c = stack.pop()

    rmin, rmax = max(0, r-1), min(r+2, m)
    cmin, cmax = max(0, c-1), min(c+2, n)

    mines = sum(cell == 'M' for row in board[rmin:rmax] for cell in row[cmin:cmax])
    if mines:
        board[r][c] = str(mines)
    else:
        board[r][c] = 'B'
        for i in range(rmin, rmax):
            for j in range(cmin, cmax):
                if board[i][j] == 'E':
                    stack.append((i, j))
                    board[i][j] = '_'    # Temporary mark to prevent repeated queueing
```

Answer (score 4):

- An `M` field is never pushed. It may only happen as a result of an unfortunate click. Testing for `board[r][c] == 'M'` in the loop is a waste of time. Test it once, `if board[click[0]][click[1]] == 'M'`, before the loop.
- Similarly, you should not bother with neighbors if the field is not blank. A test for `board[r][c] == 'B'` happens too late. As implemented, for other fields code still compute neighbors - and does nothing with them.
- The tests for `0 <= dr < m and 0 <= dc < n` *may* also cause performance issues, and do not look Pythonic. Ask forgiveness not permission, e.g.

  ```
      try:
          if board[dr][dc] == 'M':
              mines += 1
      except IndexError:
          pass
  ```
- Quite a few fields are pushed and inspected multiple times. I am not sure wether it is a bottleneck; however the right-hand and scanline methods of [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) do worth investigation.

Comment: Unfortunately, `board[-1][-1]` is not a `IndexError` so that optimization is actually a bug.  But if you ask, I’ll forgive you.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Forgiveness accepted.